# Does Synclock lock the object reference or the object itself?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, synclock

The title says it all really but I have provided some code to demonstrate what I'm asking.

```
Public Class Class1
    Private Object1 As New Class2
    Private Sub Test1()
        Dim LocalObject1 As New Class3(Object1)
        Synclock Object1
            'Some code here
        End Synclock
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class2
    'Some custom object type
End Class
Public Class Class3
    Private Object2 As Class2
    Public Sub New(ObjectIn As Class3)
        Object2 = ObjectIn
    End Sub
    Public Sub DoSomeWork()
        Synclock Object2
            'Some code here
        End Synclock
    End Sub
End Class
```

Will the two `'Some code here`s ever run concurrently (assuming that they are on seperate threads)?

Comment: Your code is pretty unclear - especially as you never initialize `Object1` in `Class1`. Can you show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem? And why is your constructor parameter `ByRef` when you're never assigning a value to it in the constructor?

Comment: @Jon I have clarified the code as per your suggestions, I hope this helps. However I do not have a complete program to demonstrate the problem as there isn't a problem just a question! I thought this would be covered in the documentation for SyncLock but it either isn't covered or my lack of understanding has missed where it is covered. Thanks for helping me clarify.

Comment: Lock state is stored in the object, not the reference.  Which is why you should never write code like this.  Other code could for example synclock the ObjectIn object and deadlock the heck out of your code.  Write `Private locker As New Object`.

Comment: @Hans So if I wanted to coordinate access to Object1 between classes what would be the right way to do it? If this should be its own question please do say and I will happily oblige.